# Is there a way in Chrome Dev tools to not jump through other JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

What I'm saying is I'm trying to see how everything is working in a particular file. My problem is even stepping over a particular line or stepping out of a function, it will still take me to a function in a separate javascript file I have (such as jQuery, particular APIs, etc) when I don't care how that works since I know the issue is with my Javascript. Is there some way I can disable jumping through those or ignore seeing them work? Like I kind of said, I only want to see how much code works in one specific file, not how the whole thing compiles and runs altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Chrome Developer tools, click 'Settings' in top-right corner:
[image: chrome tools settings]

Then, select 'Blackboxing' from the menu on the left:
[image: blackboxing]

And add patterns of all 3rd party libs which you'd like the debugger to skip.

Comment: This is now called the "Framework Ignore List" for anyone coming here